# How to select previous sibling of a parent whose child is last among the input which are not null, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have a little complicated situation here, one which, despite my serious efforts, am unable to find reasonable solution of. So I am placing it here. I have javascript, jQuery and HTML with following details:

```js
var lastDateIndex ='';
function datecheck(){
lastDateIndex = $('td, input[name=date]:not(:empty):last').prev('[name=index]');

alert(lastDateIndex.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1'>
       <tr id='row1'>
         <th>Index</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Payment</th>
         <th>Balance</th>
       </tr>
       <tr id='row2' name='row'>
         <td name='index'>1</td>
         <td name='rowdate'><input type="date" title="date1" name="date" onblur="datecheck();"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="description1" name="description"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="paymentpay1" name="paymentpay"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="balance1" name="balance"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id='row3' name='row'>
         <td name='index'>2</td>
         <td name='rowdate'><input type="date" title="date2" name="date" onblur="datecheck();"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="description2" name="description"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="paymentpay2" name="paymentpay"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="balance2" name="balance"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id='row4' name='row'>
         <td name='index'>3</td>
         <td name='rowdate'><input type="date" title="date3" name="date" onblur="datecheck();"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="description3" name="description"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="paymentpay3" name="paymentpay"></td>
         <td name='description'><input title="balance3" name="balance"></td>      
      </tr>
     </table>
```

This table has numerous input fields and all of them are to be filled by user as per his/hers need. I need to select the `td` with `name='index'` inside of last `tr` where `td` with `input[name='date']` is not null. In other words, if the user has entered date details in `input[name='date']` and  `[title='date1']` inside `tr` with `id='row2'` and has left all remaining rows to be blank, I want to select the html inside of `name='index'` inside `tr` with `id='row2'`.

The function I have written above only alerts **1**, even if all the rows except the last one are filled. How can I acheive the answer of the `html` of `name='index'` of the last `tr` with empty `name='date'`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it can't be done using only selectors, so consider the following:

1. In case the user writes a value in `input[name='date']`, update its parent `TD` and add a `class/data-*` attribute (for instance: `addClass('date-isnt-null')`).
2. Use the following selector:

`$('.tr:last-child td.date-isnt-null[name="index"]');`

Answer (score 0):

If whenever you call your function you want to output all the rows with a date entered, you can use:

```
function datecheck() {
  $('input[name=date]').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).val()) {
      console.log($(el).parents('tr').find('[name=index]').html());
    }
  });
}
```

(not sure to understand the last index bit).

As for Ofir Baruch suggestion, here is a way to go:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=date]').bind('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val()){
       $(this).parent('td').addClass("dirty");
    } else {
       // in case the user removes the date
       $(this).parent('td').removeClass("dirty"); 
    }
  });
});

function datecheck() {
   var html = $('.tr:last-child td.dirty[name="index"]').html();
   console.log(html);
}
```

On input date blur and if the user entered a date, we add the class `dirty` to its parent.

Comment: The first <td> inside each <tr> is name='index', whose html I want to output if its <td> with name='date' is empty.